# Rails 3 - named route redirecting to wrong controller action

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, routes

I'm fairly new to rails, but I have completed a couple of projects before, including the Michael Hartl Tutorial.
I'm building a simple app that stores a virtual wardrobe.
I've got 2 tables - users and items - where a user has_many items and an item belongs_to a user.
I set up the following named route in my routes.rb file:

```
match "/wardrobe", to: "items#index"
```

However, when I try to go to /wardrobe in my browser I get a no route match error as follows:

```
No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"items"}
```

I'm not sure why rails is trying to route via the show action when I've named the route through the index action.
These are the relevant actions in my ItemsController:

```
def show
  @item = Item.find(params[:id])
end

def index
  @items = Item.all
end
```

The redirect is called on create as follows:

```
def create
  @item = Item.new(params[:item])
  if @item.save
    flash[:success] = "Item added"
    redirect_to wardrobe_path                                                                                    
  else
    render 'new'
  end
end
```

rake routes provides the following:

```
wardrobe        /wardrobe(.:format)       items#index
```

So, I know the route exists.
Can anyone explain what's going on here? And how I can go about fixing it?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Try changing:

    match "/wardrobe", to: "items#index"

to

    get "/wardrobe", to: "items#index"

And use the new error to debug.

Comment: Also, what does rake routes say?

Answer (score 0):

It might be because it's rake route is called `wardrobe_path` rather than `wardrobes_path` (plural) - when it's singular Rails will default to show action I believe. That might be causing the confusion.

Comment: I'm not sure about that - I've seen that happen, but only when trying to route to the actual table name. Wardrobe isn't a table, it's just a tidier route than /items. If I visit /items, I actually get the same error, which is just weird, because it's right there in rake routes.